# Migrate old Quartz job name

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I have this old Quartz job which I would like to migrate to a new version:

```
@Component
public class SystemProcessJob implements Job {
  
  ...... 

  @Override
  protected void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException 
  {
    final JobKey key = context.getJobDetail().getKey();
    final UUID runId = UUID.fromString(key.getName());

    executeInternalProcess(runId);

    logger.info("Job Executed");
  }
```

When I run it I get error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string: jobDetail
```

What should be the proper way to migrate this code? I need to generate manual `UUID runId` or get the UUID rom the job?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the IllegalArgumentException because UUID.fromString is expecting you to provide a real UUID which should look like "24b7cc4e-a3ba-4ee7-b0e3-1ccdda09ec30" 32 digit hexadecimal number [check](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID()), it is getting "jobDetail" as UUID and throwing the exception.

Without knowing the full context of the project. If you want to use a UUID as the job identifier in Quartz, you should ensure that you're setting the job name to a valid UUID string when you're creating the job. Here's an example of how you can do this:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class QuartzDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(QuartzDemoApplication.class, args);
        onStartup();
    }

    private static void onStartup() throws SchedulerException {
        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(SystemProcessJob.class)
                .withIdentity(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "group1") // set job name to a valid UUID
                .build();

        Date afterFiveSeconds = Date.from(LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(5)
                .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .startAt(afterFiveSeconds)
                .build();

        SchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
}
```

now the method below will bring the UUID as you wanted

```java
@Override
protected void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException
{
  final JobKey key = context.getJobDetail().getKey();
  final UUID runId = UUID.fromString(key.getName());

  executeInternalProcess(runId);

  logger.info("Job Executed");
}
```

I do not know the how the UUID is used in `executeInternalProcess` personally I would use only `UUID.randomUUID()` instead of `UUID.fromString` this will lower the complexity, And if you do not see any problems you don't need to create that job at the beginning with the random UUID.

```java
@Override
protected void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException
{
  final UUID runId = UUID.randomUUID();

  executeInternalProcess(runId);

  logger.info("Job Executed");
}
```